# Use Access VB.net to change background color of form control

Tags: vb.net

I want to change the label's backgroundcolor so it gradually changes, but for some reason I can't use the RGB function. 
and my teacher isn't a real help cause he doesn't realy teach please help

```
Public Class Form1
Dim r, g, b As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = False

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    r = 0
    g = 0
    b = 0

    For r = 1 To 225
        r += 1
        LblColor.BackColor = RGB(r, g, b)
    Next
    For g = 1 To 255
        g += 1
        LblColor.BackColor = RGB(r, g, b)
    Next
    For b = 1 To 255
        b += 1
        LblColor.BackColor = RGB(r, g, b)
    Next

End Sub

Private Function RGB(r As Integer, g As Integer, b As Integer) As Color

End Function

Private Sub LblColor_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LblColor.Click

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oke so i found out that for VB.Net I have to use this:`LblColor.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)` and now it is working thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The `RGB()` function is built-in to VBA.  Try removing your own version -- it's prolly getting in the way.

```
Private Function RGB()...  '  |   
   ...                        |    <--- remove this bit
End Function                  |
```

Comment: if i do that it underlines "RGB(r, g, b)" and sais that "integer" can't be converted to color

Comment: Try color.FromRGB.  As Smandoli points out, redefining the function (but then leaving it empty) isn't going to get you far.